# Cannot format data to make boxplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am attempting to make a boxplot on RStudio with the variables 'Control' and 'Experimental', but each control needs to have 2 subsets of data ('Day' and 'Night'). So essentially I want 4 separate box-and-whisker plots on one plot (if that makes any sense at all?).

I have two separate data frames with the headings 'Day', 'Night', and 'Hue', so would need day and night on the x-axis, and hue on the y-axis. I have tried re-arranging my data frame to have 2 columns ('Time' eg day/night, and 'Hue') but ggplot2 doesnt seem to like this either.

I literally can't get these plots to work at all,so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

ETA:
Actual Data:

1   Group   Hue

2   1   0.26

3   1   0.39

4   1   0.23

5   1   0.24

6   1   0.05

7   1   0.71

8   1   0.59

9   1   0.78

10  1   0.63

11  1   1.09

12  1   0.18

13  1   0.83

14  1   0.20

15  1   0.15

16  1   0.17

17  1   0.24

18  1   0.42

19  1   0.38

20  1   0.61

21  1   0.49

22  1   0.46

23  1   0.50

24  1   0.41

25  1   0.23

26  1   0.11

27  1   0.47

28  1   0.15

29  1   0.40

30  1   0.31

31  1   0.34

32  2   1.37

33  2   0.21

4   2   0.48

35  2   0.10

36  2   0.82

37  2   0.63

38  2   0.48

39  2   0.70
40  2   0.68
41  2   0.76
42  2   0.52
43  2   0.68
44  2   2.62
45  2   0.13
46  2   0.40
47  2   0.39
48  2   0.41
49  2   0.50
50  2   0.66
51  2   0.56
52  2   0.58
53  2   0.17
54  2   0.47
55  2   0.31
56  2   0.39
57  2   0.49
58  2   0.38
59  2   0.48
60  2   0.47
61  2   0.40
62  3   1.16
63  3   0.30
64  3   0.40
65  3   0.53
66  3   0.30
67  3   0.39
68  3   0.38
69  3   0.36
70  3   0.35
71  3   0.34
72  3   0.39
73  3   0.47
74  3   0.37
75  3   0.52
76  3   0.52
77  3   0.50
78  3   0.48
79  3   0.55
80  3   0.62
81  3   0.59
82  3   0.26
83  3   0.39
84  3   0.23
85  3   0.24
86  3   0.47
87  3   0.71
88  3   0.59
89  3   0.78
90  3   0.48
91  3   0.37
92  4   1.43
93  4   0.46
94  4   1.26
95  4   2.65
96  4   1.43
97  4   0.38
98  4   0.35
99  4   0.59
100 4   1.38
101 4   0.51
102 4   1.12
103 4   0.42
104 4   0.43
105 4   0.36
106 4   0.62
107 4   1.60
108 4   0.58
109 4   1.57
110 4   0.43
111 4   1.19
112 4   0.77
113 4   1.37
114 4   2.21
115 4   1.48
116 4   0.20
117 4   2.82
118 4   0.63
119 4   0.48
120 4   2.58
121 4   0.43

Whereas R is putting this data into my boxplot:
Group
Hue

1   Control Day 12.43503

2   Control Day 15.50208

3   Control Day 10.55415

4   Control Day 14.55953

5   Control Day 14.81230

6   Control Day 17.17195

7   Control Day 16.72419

8   Control Day 12.82169

9   Control Day 12.71106

10  Control Day 12.39931

11  Control Day 16.41781

12  Control Day 17.60299

13  Control Day 14.94367

14  Control Day 19.76444

15  Control Day 18.16637

16  Control Day 13.53893

17  Control Day 12.13074

18  Control Day 13.79023

19  Control Day 11.37030

20  Control Day 18.51498

21  Control Day 16.43221

22  Control Day 10.87997

23  Control Day 17.54314

24  Control Day 17.46402

25  Control Day 19.95249

26  Control Day 14.50452

27  Control Day 18.43108

28  Control Day 13.29810

29  Control Day 10.05007

30  Control Day 13.79817

31  Control Night   18.61311

32  Control Night   11.38397

33  Control Night   14.95923

34  Control Night   14.06546
35  Control Night   12.49782
36  Control Night   12.32807
37  Control Night   14.51005
38  Control Night   12.62860
39  Control Night   19.34517
40  Control Night   18.93672
41  Control Night   12.43503
42  Control Night   15.50208
43  Control Night   10.55415
44  Control Night   14.55953
45  Control Night   14.81230
46  Control Night   17.17195
47  Control Night   16.72419
48  Control Night   12.82169
49  Control Night   12.71106
50  Control Night   12.39931
51  Control Night   16.41781
52  Control Night   17.60299
53  Control Night   14.94367
54  Control Night   19.76444
55  Control Night   18.16637
56  Control Night   13.53893
57  Control Night   12.13074
58  Control Night   13.79023
59  Control Night   11.37030
60  Control Night   18.51498
61  Experiment Day  16.43221
62  Experiment Day  10.87997
63  Experiment Day  17.54314
64  Experiment Day  17.46402
65  Experiment Day  19.95249
66  Experiment Day  14.50452
67  Experiment Day  18.43108
68  Experiment Day  13.29810
69  Experiment Day  10.05007
70  Experiment Day  13.79817
71  Experiment Day  18.61311
72  Experiment Day  11.38397
73  Experiment Day  14.95923
74  Experiment Day  14.06546
75  Experiment Day  12.49782
76  Experiment Day  12.32807
77  Experiment Day  14.51005
78  Experiment Day  12.62860
79  Experiment Day  19.34517
80  Experiment Day  18.93672
81  Experiment Day  12.43503
82  Experiment Day  15.50208
83  Experiment Day  10.55415
84  Experiment Day  14.55953
85  Experiment Day  14.81230
86  Experiment Day  17.17195
87  Experiment Day  16.72419
88  Experiment Day  12.82169
89  Experiment Day  12.71106
90  Experiment Day  12.39931
91  Experiment Night    16.41781
92  Experiment Night    17.60299
93  Experiment Night    14.94367
94  Experiment Night    19.76444
95  Experiment Night    18.16637
96  Experiment Night    13.53893
97  Experiment Night    12.13074
98  Experiment Night    13.79023
99  Experiment Night    11.37030
100 Experiment Night    18.51498
101 Experiment Night    16.43221
102 Experiment Night    10.87997
103 Experiment Night    17.54314
104 Experiment Night    17.46402
105 Experiment Night    19.95249
106 Experiment Night    14.50452
107 Experiment Night    18.43108
108 Experiment Night    13.29810
109 Experiment Night    10.05007
110 Experiment Night    13.79817
111 Experiment Night    18.61311
112 Experiment Night    11.38397
113 Experiment Night    14.95923
114 Experiment Night    14.06546
115 Experiment Night    12.49782
116 Experiment Night    12.32807
117 Experiment Night    14.51005
118 Experiment Night    12.62860
119 Experiment Night    19.34517
120 Experiment Night    18.93672

Comment: I think it's better if you can provide a working example, or have snippets of your code. That being said, from what you are describing, I'd recommend merging the datasets into one and use grouping, coloring and facets to achieve your plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I would recommend merging your two dataframes, so you have two columns: Group (including Control Day, Control Night, Experiment Day, Experiment Night), and Hue.

So your data would be structured like the output from this (example data only):

```
data<-data.frame(Group=rep(c(rep("Control Day",10),rep("Control Night",10),
                  rep("Experiment Day",10),rep("Experiment Night",10))),
                 Hue=runif(40,10,20))
```

Then your plot should work by:

```
plot<-ggplot(data,aes(x=factor(Group),y=Hue))+
  geom_boxplot()
plot
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped so much! The hue axis ranges from 0.0 to 20.0, and my data is between 0.05 and 3, any idea how I can adjust the hue axis accordingly? When I opened my data in R, there were only 30 data points rather than 120 (eg 10 data points per category, rather than 30), how do I fix this so that it's plotting all of my data? Thanks again!

Comment: I fixed the 120 data points, but the data isn't the same data as from my original document. I'm very confused!

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing your original and current data, I can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: I'll edit the original post with the data I have, and the data R is feeding into my plots.

Comment: I've added the data but its quite hard to format, so I hope you can understand it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: What code are you using to read in or get the second dataset?

Comment: Oh, ok - that is the problem then. The first block of code I gave was just an example (I just invented some data). If you leave that part out, and just run the second part of code (the one with the plot), then that should work for your data. I will adjust my code above to make one more change that you will need if you are using numbers as your groups.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense! Thank you, thank you, thank you.